# GA Open Email Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to know how many of my clients **open** the automatic emails my website sents (ex Order Received etc).
Is there any detailed guide for newbies out there? I found several tutorials but they are really old. I use GA Universal Tracking.

Comment: Google evangelist Cutroni has an recent article about that: http://cutroni.com/blog/2014/07/15/using-offline-and-online-data-to-drive-google-analytics-remarketing/. However as it stand I guess the question is off-topic for SO ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic "), so you might want to rephrase it to ask for a solution instead of external tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Nice post, I have tried something similar but it did not work out very well for myself so I then started using ContactMonkey & have been very happy with the service they provide.

The recipient of your email doesn't need to acknowledge the read receipt. The tracking just happens in the background.

You can check out [ContactMonkey by visiting their site](https://contactmonkey.com/)

Hope that helps!